# Cracking hashes of trivially modified passwords

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking

If I started with “password”, then change it to “password2”, “password3” etc, is that easier to crack the hashes of the set of passwords than if I used only the original password?

Does having the output of hash(password1), hash(password2), etc. make it easier to crack the complete set than having only hash(password)?

Comment: So, this isn't about changing passwords, or cracked passwords, this is *entirely* about the hash? If that's what you meant originally, you could have written the question very differently (and added the `hash` tag)... And my answer below answers you ...

Answer (score 1):

Password hashes are designed so that even small changes in text result in nearly random results. Once you add a salt, which all password hashing schemes should use, even if you used the same password, the hash would be different.